# Show field when the other one is empty on Drupal 9 editing content

Tags: paragraphs

I'm pretty new on Drupal I probably only have one month using it.

I have two fields on a paragraph type, "field_text1" is a Text(plain,long) and the other one, "field_text2" is a Text(formatted,long). Essentially I want to show field_text2 while field_text1 is empty and hide field_text1, but if field_text1 has content I want to hide field_text2 in the node edit form.

I tried searching for some solutions on google but all of them where for older Drupal versions and very confusing.

Comment: Using twig only solves it at the theme level - it does not solve it in any admin form level. I would personally rethink the approach, as editing paragraph subforms is not exactly easy. maybe https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields

Comment: @Kevin is there a way of doing this by creating a custom module? Like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D9hu5uaQ0Fk

Comment: I would just try conditional fields. If you haven't developed a module before you'll be in over your head pretty quick with paragraph forms.